# Folders disappearing from search result list after consulting them

Tags: finder, spotlight, folders, search

We have a customer that is experiencing a strange behavior when he searches folders on his MacBook (Catalina 10.15.7, i7 2.2Ghz, 16GB Ram).

For example :

- he searches for "2022-D00170" which returns a list of two folders and four files
- he double clicks on the first folder named exactly 2022-D00170 and sees the files within, in the same Finder window
- he then clicks on the back arrow of the Finder window to get back to the search results
- the folder he went in is no longer in the results list, only one folder and four files show up
- he does the same with the other folder and when getting back to the search results it is also gone
- he then opens one of the four files, a PDF that opens with Adobe Reader
- the PDF file also disppears from the Finder search results

If we close the Finder search and reopen a new Finder window, do the same search for "2022-D00170" we only get the remaining three files, the two folders and the PDF are gone from the results...

We forced quit (Relaunch) the Finder application, same result. Only rebooting the Mac will reset the search and the behavior starts again after the user searches again.

We did not reset Spotlight yet as it seems the files and folders are indexed correctly.

Anyone has an idea of what is going on and a fix or a workaround we could try? We do not want to have the user reboot his MacBook each time he needs to search for documents...

Thanks for reading.

OCIM

Comment: Are these folders local to the Mac (either internal or external) or a networked drive of some sort?

Comment: Local to the MacBook. In a folder in the home directory of the user.